# Convert columns to rows and a column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to convert columns to rows in SQL Server:

```
Id   Value  Jan1  Jan2
----------------------
1     2      25    35
2     5      45    45
```

result should be

```
Id  Value Month 1  2
----------------------
1    2     Jan  25 35
2    5     Jan  45 45
```

How can I get this result? Anyone please help

Comment: Your sample and desired results are a little thin.  Are these days of the year or Year-Over-Years?   Will there be multiple months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking seems a little strange. If I extend your example to include columns for `Feb1` and `Feb2`, then I see two options for transposing your columns from this:

```
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+
| Id | Value | Jan1 | Jan2 | Feb1 | feb2 |
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |     2 |   25 |   35 |   15 |   28 |
|  2 |     5 |   45 |   45 |   60 |   60 |
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+
```

Transpose just the month part:

```
select Id, Value, MonthName, MonthValue1, MonthValue2
from t
  cross apply (values ('Jan',Jan1,Jan2),('Feb',Feb1,Feb2)
    ) v (MonthName,MonthValue1,MonthValue2)
```

returns:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| Id | Value | MonthName | MonthValue1 | MonthValue2 |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |     2 | Jan       |          25 |          35 |
|  1 |     2 | Feb       |          15 |          28 |
|  2 |     5 | Jan       |          45 |          45 |
|  2 |     5 | Feb       |          60 |          60 |
+----+-------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Or completely transpose the month columns like so:

```
select Id, Value, MonthName, MonthValue
from t
  cross apply (values ('Jan1',Jan1),('Jan2',Jan2),('Feb1',Feb1),('Feb2',Feb2)
    ) v (MonthName,MonthValue)
```

returns:

```
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
| Id | Value | MonthName | MonthValue |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |     2 | Jan1      |         25 |
|  1 |     2 | Jan2      |         35 |
|  1 |     2 | Feb1      |         15 |
|  1 |     2 | Feb2      |         28 |
|  2 |     5 | Jan1      |         45 |
|  2 |     5 | Jan2      |         45 |
|  2 |     5 | Feb1      |         60 |
|  2 |     5 | Feb2      |         60 |
+----+-------+-----------+------------+
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KZV45690

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be:

```
select Id, Value, 'Jan' as [month], Jan1 as [1], Jan2 as [2]
from t;
```

You are basically just adding another column to the output.

I don't recommend using numbers as column names, nor SQL Server keywords such as `month`.

Comment: ,Month column is not available.Remove Month column from SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option that you won't have to specify up to 365 fields

```
Declare @YourTable table (Id int,Value int,Jan1 int,Jan2 int,Feb1 int, Feb2 int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,     2,      25,    35, 100, 101),
(2,     5,      45,    45, 200, 201)


Select [Id],[Value],[Month],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31]
 From (
        Select A.Id
              ,A.Value
              ,[Month]   = Left(C.Item,3)
              ,[Col]     = substring(C.Item,4,5)
              ,[Measure] = C.Value
         From  @YourTable A
         Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml)) B
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                              ,Value  = attr.value('.','int') 
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                         Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','Value')
                     ) C
      ) A
 Pivot (sum(Measure) For [Col] in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31]) ) p
```

**Returns**

[image]